# EEPROM emulation on stm32 using HAL drivers

Tags: stm32, flash-memory, eeprom, stm32f0

I am trying to emulate EEPROM on stm32f0. There is an [application note](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/2e/d4/65/6b/87/dd/40/25/DM00049914.pdf/files/DM00049914.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00049914.pdf) provided by STM.

In the sample `main.c`,

```
int main(void)
{
  /*!< At this stage the microcontroller clock setting is already configured, 
       this is done through SystemInit() function which is called from startup
       file (startup_stm32f0xx.s) before to branch to application main.
       To reconfigure the default setting of SystemInit() function, refer to
       system_stm32f0xx.c file
     */  
   /* Unlock the Flash Program Erase controller */
  FLASH_Unlock();

  /* EEPROM Init */
  EE_Init();

/* --- Store successively many values of the three variables in the EEPROM ---*/
  /* Store 0x1000 values of Variable1 in EEPROM */
  for (VarValue = 1; VarValue <= 0x64; VarValue++)
  {
    EE_WriteVariable(VirtAddVarTab[0], VarValue);
  }

  /* read the last stored variables data*/
  EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddVarTab[0], &VarDataTab[0]);


  /* Store 0x2000 values of Variable2 in EEPROM */
  for (VarValue = 1; VarValue <= 0xC8; VarValue++)
  {
    EE_WriteVariable(VirtAddVarTab[1], VarValue);
  }

  /* read the last stored variables data*/
  EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddVarTab[0], &VarDataTab[0]);
  EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddVarTab[1], &VarDataTab[1]);


  /* Store 0x3000 values of Variable3 in EEPROM */
  for (VarValue = 1; VarValue <= 0x1C2; VarValue++)
  {
    EE_WriteVariable(VirtAddVarTab[2], VarValue);
  }

  /* read the last stored variables data*/
  EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddVarTab[0], &VarDataTab[0]);
  EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddVarTab[1], &VarDataTab[1]);
  EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddVarTab[2], &VarDataTab[2]);

  while (1);
}
```

`Flash_Unlock()` is a function used in STM standard peripheral library. However, I am using CubeMX that auto-generates code that uses HAL drivers. Is `Flash_Unlock()` necessary to be called before one can use the EEPROM_emulation APIs? If yes, what is the HAL equivalent for calling `Flash_Unlock()`? Any special configuration settings to make on CubeMX to use EEPROM emulation?

Comment: You're looking for `HAL_FLASH_Unlock()`, but STM32Cube does provide examples for some boards, for example `STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.21.0/Projects/STM32F4-Discovery/Applications/EEPROM/EEPROM_Emulation`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ST Microelectronics did provide sample code using HAL drivers. The problem is their documentation is all over the place and googling may not land you the right page.

This is the right [document](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/75/1e/68/3e/bd/8d/41/a1/DM00210690/files/DM00210690.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00210690.pdf) for you.

Search for "EEPROM_Emulation". You will find that the sample code is provided under NUCLEO -F091RC firmware examples. The sample code should answer your questions.

Comment: Been googling this hi & lo, but never realized I have had it all this while in CubeMX repo..Thanks a lot.